# How to import only one package from google play services lib

Tags: java, android, eclipse

like in the title :

I'm developing in eclipse an android application, and I don't want to import all the Libraries of google play services_lib.

Is there a way to import only one package that I need?, and is it legal to do like that? 
(because I read that those libraries are not modifiable).

Answer (score 0):

First thing please use Android studio.
Yes using these libraries individually is absolutely legal.

[Here you can find them all.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) (Individual)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have problems in running Android Studio , solution not possible in Eclipse ?

Comment: @رشيدرشيد If you have the problem with running AS, ask another question. Maybe you will get answer how to run it.